# Optimized Sql query for combining two tables?

Tags: java, sql, optimization

Hi I have this real time problem for my project, say i have two tables

TABLE STUDENT & TABLE CLASSATTENDANCEHISTORY, (names are imaginary)

```
STUDENT
NAME, ID, LAST_TIME_SEEN_IN_COLEGE,


CLASSHISTORY
CLASSNAME, ID, STUDENT_ID, LAST_TIME_PRESENT,
```

" Now i want to delete all the list of students who's student.last_time_seen_in_colege > classHistory.last_time_present "

As both the tables, lets say will have millions of rows, So i thought of doing it in Batches like, 50 Batches at a time, or the table will be lock for a very long time, these two tables are very active tables.

Lots of operations will be there for both tables so i thought of using in batches.

Whether JOIN OR SUBQUERY WILL BE BEST ? OR CAN I STORED WHOLE TABLE IN JAVA MEMORY AND THAN PROCESS ? Please some expert advice i want it to be best ?

I know we can use Inner join but i want to know the efficient way to do it, If i say do inner join each time for 50 batches that inner join will search whole table everytime.

Comment: WHY DO YOU SHOUT? please respond (also just try it, I guess joins work fine and Java will likely run out of memory, but see for yourself)

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server? Please remove the tag it's not for.

Comment: Even with millions of records the join should be very efficient if you have appropriate indexes.  You should be able to do the delete in one simple sql statement (and if you absolutely need to you could add a limit clause and repeatedly execute the query until it returns 0 records modified).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I already know that, I was expecting more efficient way ! That's very common approach, which everyone does, and i am using Sql,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from student where id in ( select id from student s where exists (select null from classhistory c where s.last_time_seen_in_college > c.last_time_present )
```

above query will work in this case.

explanation on ask tom when to use join and when to go for sub query 
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:66812779016023

java is not an option in this case as you mentioned that table will have millions of rows to select those millions of rows and storing them into result set and then processing them will take a lot more time then we can imagine.

Comment: As i already mentioned, the tables name and structure are imaginary ! I gave the names to have a clear understanding.

Comment: The link was usefull, but the last questioned was unanswered ? What role does exists play to make it more fast ?

Comment: in case if you just want to check existence of 1 entity in other table exists is best solution.for example suppose there are 2 table student,library_entries,in student there are 3 entries for student_id 1,2,3 respectively.In library there are 30 entries ,20 for student_id 1 and 10 for student id 2 and you just need to check whether particular id is present or absent in other table in such cases exists is beneficial.in case if you want to retrieve all the matching rows from table joins are more beneficial. hope it helps